# erro: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in

Tags: php

Tou organizando as pastas de um CRUDizinho que tou fazendo aqui. porém tou com um baita problema. Obrigado pessoal!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui].

listarMotos.php

```
function __autoload($classes) {
include("../classes/{$classes}.php");
}
require_once '../includes/topo.php';
require_once '../includes/menu.php';
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: E a pasta `modais`?

Comment: não estou usando a pasta modais no arquivo listarMotos.php. A intenção é apenas o topo.php e menu.php

Answer (score 1):

É mais recomendado utilizar a função abaixo para autoload. Os nomes no file_exists vai depender das pastas que estão seus arquivos de classe. Considerei apenas a sua pasta classes.

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class){
  if(file_exists('classes/'.$class.'.php')) {
    require_once 'classses/'.$class.'.php';
  }
});
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Referência:
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.autoload.php

Answer (score 0):

Vasculhei tudo na internet e achei:

```
<?php
include(dirname(__FILE__) . "/includes/topo.php");
include(dirname(__FILE__) . "/includes/menu.php");
?>
```

Mesmo assim da o erro:
failed to open stream: No such file or directory.

é bronca :(